# how to locate the php interpreter for netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, ide, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I could not know how to locate the netbeans interpreter, I have installed the xampp on linux Ubuntu and now i am trying to select the interpreter in netbeans but I could not know which file to select, in which folder can I find the php to be selected for the interpreter?

Answer (score 2):

First you must install php:

```
sudo apt-get install php
```

then you just put this to the path of interpreter:

```
/usr/bin/php
```